# Performing unit test for dynamo db functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to unit testing and wanted to perform some tests on the below listed functions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would call an integration test, as opposed to unittest.

Boto3 supply a library you can use for unittests: [Stubber](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html).

For a unit test (as I've not used it for DynamoDB) - this tutorial looks like a good place to start:
https://blog.milancermak.com/2019/02/14/unit-testing-aws-services-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

- Indent the class body.
- You need to mark your tests as tests. If you are using  unittest, your class should subclass  `unittest.TestCase`
- It's not officially a unit test if you access databases, but in practice it is fine.
- The test doesn't test much. It just inserts objects. That actually has value, but it would be better if you tested a meaningful sequence of behavior. Maybe retrieve the objects and compare input to output.
- You call `to_db` twice. Are you sure the first param ( `batch ) as passed in`to_dynamo_db_in_batches`is really a`boto` object?